# Reading String words before and after a certain symbol

Tags: java

although I've already asked a question about similar problem  how to make JAVA split a String line into two parts, I did not get the result I wanted. My project deals with logical electrical circuit (Gates, Wires, Signals, Contacts...). What I need to do in the method below is to **SEPARATE** **incoming contacts** from **outgoing ones**. If there is a passed into the method String is `A B C -> D` and `A B C` are incoming and `D` is outgoing contact. My code reads everything before the symbol `->` but I need that to read after that symbol too ignoring the symbol itself. I have to test `incoming contacts` and `outgoing contacts` separately and tests are also below. Can smb help ?

```
 private List<Contact> inputs;
    private List<Wire> innerWires;

    public void parseContactsLine(String line)
            {

        String[] words = line.split(" ");


                for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
                {
                    if(!(words[i].equals("->")))
                    {
                        Wire wire1 = new Wire(words[i]);
                        ///Wire wire2 = new Wire(words[i]);
                        innerWires.add(wire1);
                        //innerWires.add(wire2);
                        Contact contact = new Contact(wire1, wire1, true);
                        inputs.add(contact);
                        outputs.add(contact);
                    }
                    else 
                        break;
                }
        }
```

My output from this code is `[A B C]`

My test cases are:

```
 List<Contact> ins = Arrays.asList(new Contact[]{
      new Contact(new Wire("A"), new Wire("A"), true),
        new Contact(new Wire("B"), new Wire("B"), true),
        new Contact(new Wire("C"), new Wire("C"), true)}
    );
    List<Contact> outs = Arrays.asList(new Contact[]{
      new Contact(new Wire("D"), new Wire("D"), false)}
    );
```

Notice that `incoming contacts` and `outgoing contacts` are tested separately! Do not pay much attentiong to `Wire` and `Contact` members. They are defined correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
String[] array = "A B C -> D".split("->");
    //splits your string into two strings, and stores them in an array
    //array[0] = "A B C " -- all elements before ->
    //array[1] = " D" -- all elements after ->
    String[] input = array[0].trim().split(" "); 
    // trim is used to remove trailing/leading white spaces
     String[] output = array[1].trim().split(" ");
```

Comment: What do array[0] and array[1] represent alongside with trim()? @coder

Comment: first you split based on "->", this will split your string into two parts "A B C" (array[0]) and " D" (array[1]). Trim is used to remove trailing and leading white spaces. Then you can split them on white space to get individual inputs A, B, C and D

Comment: Your code is close to what I want! Base on this I've changed my method., thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can loop the words array till you find the -> symbol. When you find the symbol, you actually have found the index of -> in the array. So, then you can loop the words array again with a something like: `for(int x = symbolIndex + 1; x < words.lenght; x++)`

(symbolIndex + 1 assures the loop's ignoring the symbol)